# error messages fitting a non-linear exponential model between two variables

Tags: r, exponential, nls

I have two variables that I'm trying to model the relationship between and extract the residuals. The relationship between the two variables is clearly a non-linear exponential relationship. I've tried a few different approaches with nls, but I keep getting different error messages.

[image]

```
# dataset
df <- structure(list(y = c(464208.56, 334962.43, 361295.68, 426535.68, 258843.93, 272855.46, 
   166322.72, 244695.28, 227003.03, 190728.4, 156025.45, 72594.24, 56911.4, 175328.95, 161199.76, 
   152520.77, 190610.57, 60734.34, 31620.9, 74518.86, 45524.49, 2950.58, 2986.38, 15961.77, 12484.05, 
   6828.41, 2511.72, 1656.12, 5271.4, 7550.66, 3357.71, 3620.43, 3699.85, 3337.56, 4106.55, 3526.66, 
   2996.79, 1649.89, 4561.64, 1724.25, 3877.2, 4426.69, 8557.61, 6021.61, 6074.17, 4072.77, 4032.95, 
   5280.16, 7127.22), 
   x = c(39.23, 38.89, 38.63, 38.44, 38.32, 38.27, 38.3, 38.4, 38.56, 38.79, 39.06, 39.36, 39.68, 
   40.01, 40.34, 40.68, 41.05, 41.46, 41.93, 42.48, 43.14, 43.92, 44.84, 45.9, 47.1, 48.4, 49.78, 
   51.2, 52.62, 54.01, 55.31, 56.52, 57.6, 58.54, 59.33, 59.98, 60.46, 60.78, 60.94, 60.92, 60.71, 
   60.3, 59.69, 58.87, 57.86, 56.67, 55.33, 53.87, 52.33)), 
   row.names = c(NA, -49L), 
   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
   na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `51` = 51L), 
   class = "omit"))

# initial model
m <- nls(y ~  a * exp(r * x), 
         start = list(a = 0.5, r = -0.2), 
         data = df)
Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(r * x), start = list(a = 0.5, r = -0.2), data = df,  : singular gradient

# add term for alg
m <- nls(y ~  a * exp(r * x), 
         start = list(a = 0.5, r = -0.2), 
         data = df,
         alg = "plinear")
Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(r * x), start = list(a = 0.5, r = -0.2), data = df,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

Comment: I would note that for the equation `y = a * exp(r * x)`, the way to think about `a` is the `y` value when `x = 0`. Looking at your plot, when `x` is around 40, the y values are around 300,000, and those values would be exponentially bigger as x approaches 0, so `a = 0.5` is a pretty terrible starting value, off by many orders of magnitude. In fact, since your data doesn't get anywhere close to `x = 0`, a shifted exponential model might be a much better fit, maybe `y ~  a * exp(r * (x - b))` with a possible start values of `a = 5e5` and `b = 38`. (Though I still get a singular gradient there)

Comment: Is there any reason not to linearize your model by modeling `log(y)`? `lm(log(y) ~ x, data = df)` fits just fine, and you can exponentiate the intercept to get `a` and use the `x` coefficient as `r` (which is `-0.1915`, very close to the `r = -0.2` starting value you use). The error structure is a little different, not sure if you care about that... The intercept is 19.1994, so `exp(19.1994) = 217868015`, which is off from you 0.5 by about `10^9` times.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. I was trying to avoid a transformation that I'd have to backtransform at a later data. Also, when I plotted a log(y), there's still a strong non-linear pattern in the data.

Comment: Not logging the data doesn't get rid of the nonlinear pattern in the logged data, it just makes it harder to see.  If you want more accuracy you could fit `log(y) ~ poly(x, 2)` ....

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks for this suggestion. I ended up using this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### log-Gaussian GLM

As @Gregor Thomas suggests you could linearize your problem (fit a log-linear regression), at the cost of changing the error model.  (Basic model diagnostics, i.e. a scale-location plot, suggest that this would be a **much** better statistical model!) However, you can do this efficiently *without* changing the error structure by fitting a log-link Gaussian GLM:

```r
m1 <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link = "log"), data = df)
```

The model is `y ~ Normal(exp(b0 + b1*x), s)`, so `a = exp(b0)`, `r = b1`.

I tried using `list(a=exp(coef(m1)[1]), r=coef(m1)[2])` as starting values, but even this was too finicky for `nls()`.

There are two ways to get `nls` to work.

### shifted exponential

As @GregorThomas suggests, shifting the x-axis to x=38 also works fine (given a sensible starting value):

```r
m <- nls(y ~  a * exp(r * (x-38)), 
         start = list(a = 3e5, r = -0.35), 
         data = df)
```

### provide nls with a gradient

The `deriv` function will generate a function with the right structure for `nls` (returns the objective function, with a ".grad" attribute giving a vector of derivatives) if you ask it nicely. (I'm also using the exponentiated intercept from the log-Gaussian GLM as a starting value ...)

```r
f <- deriv( ~ a*exp(r*x), c("a", "r"), function.arg = c("x", "a", "r"))
m2 <- nls(y ~  f(x, a, r),
         start = list(a = exp(coef(m1)[1]), r = -0.35),
         data = df)
```

We can plot these to compare the predictions (visually identical):

```r
par(las = 1, bty = "l")
xvec <- seq(38, 60, length = 101)
plot(y ~ x, df)
lines(xvec, predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(x=xvec), type = "response"),
      col = 2)
lines(xvec, predict(m, newdata = data.frame(x=xvec)), col = 4,  lty = 2)
lines(xvec, predict(m2, newdata = data.frame(x=xvec)), col = 5,  lty = 2)
```

[image]

With a little bit of extra work (exponentiating the intercept for the Gaussian GLM, shifting the x-origin back to zero for the `nls` fit) we can compare the coefficients (only equal up to a tolerance of 2e-4 but that should be good enough, right?)

```r
a1 <- exp(coef(m1)[[1]])
a2 <- coef(m)[[1]]*exp(-38*coef(m)[[2]])
all.equal(c(a = a1, r = coef(m)[[2]]),
          c(a = a2, r = coef(m1)[[2]]), tolerance = 1e-4)
all.equal(c(a = a1, r = coef(m)[[2]]),
          coef(m2), tolerance = 2e-4)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!  It's really helpful to see that all three of these different approaches give a similar answer. Since I'm planning to extract the residual values, would there be a preference between any of the models?

Comment: At a quick check, they all give identical residuals as well.  As I mentioned in my answer, if you care about the statistical properties of this fit (e.g. homoscedasticity), then you should definitely consider fitting `lm(log(y) ~ x, df)` instead ...

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes, the heteroskedasticity is quite obvious in all these options.